# Why does this simple LINQ query syntax statement not translate to method syntax?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Here's the query syntax version:

```
DataGridViewRowCollection mydgvrs = new DataGridView().Rows;

IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> a =
 from DataGridViewRow row in mydgvrs
 where row.Height > 0
 select row;
```

which is fine, and the method syntax version:

```
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> a2 =
 mydgvrs.Where(row => row.Height > 0);
```

which the complier rejects - "no extension method Where ... could be found"?

What's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the type specified in the query syntax version. (The DataGridViewRow in `from DataGridViewRow row`).

To translate this, you'll need a `Cast<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> a2 = mydgvrs.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                         .Where(row => row.Height > 0);
```

This is required since `mydgvrs` implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`.

Comment: Thanks Reed, that works. But I don't see why the Enumerable.Cast<T> is needed. Surely it is casting DataGridViewRow objects to DataGridViewRow i.e. making no change to the type. I.e .Where already has the type info it needs. Do please be kind enough to explain, if you have the time. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: mydgvrs is probably a `DataGridViewRowCollection`, which predates generics.  If you look at the docs, it implements `IEnumerable`, but **not** `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`.  The method just sees it coming through as a bunch of `System.Object` instances without the cast.  That's why your query syntax needs `from DataGridViewRow row` instead of just `from row` - normally, you don't need the type specification there, either.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: Refer to the docs for this class at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.aspx

Comment: OK, I see - an outdated interface. Thanks very much.